# Best and fastest method to add only unique records based on certain fields in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model with multiple fields where data is text type for the most part. I want to put a validation that from now on if a new record is being added, it should be unique based on 3 fields. Here one of the fields is a one-to-many field as is in another table.

I can try fetching all the records and start checking them using for-loop. I tried using annotate but it seems to help if the record is already in the table, but I want to do this validation before adding. I need a fast method for this validation.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.TextField(default='{}', null=True)
    sub_brand = models.CharField(null=True)
    .
    .
    .

class ProductNetWeight(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_net_weight')
    net_weight = models.CharField(null=True)
```

Comment: Look at `unique=True` in field definition. Or unique_together

Comment: Can you clarify how it should be unique based on the related field? Give an example, where a product has 2 product_net_weight related. Where should this check be performed? you can't create a new product with same brand and sub_brand and...?

Answer (score 0):

First you modify your model to guarantee uniqueness like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.TextField(default='{}', null=True)
    sub_brand = models.CharField(null=True)
    .
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['brand', 'sub_brand']
```

Then when inserting a new product for example un can use `get_or_create` like this:

```
product, created = Product.objects.get_or_create(brand='my brand', sub_brand='my sub brand')
```

If the product already exists, it will be returned in `product` and `created` is going to be `False`, otherwise it will return a new product and `created` is going to be `True`